# Add 2 column from 2 dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas, could you help me with the case belove pls
I have 2 DF:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['name', 'color', 'city', 'animal'], 'number': ['1', '32', '22', '13']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['name', 'color', 'city', 'animal'], 'number': ['12', '2', '42', '15']})

df1
    A       number
0   name    1
1   color   32
2   city    22
3   animal  13
DF1
    A       number
0   name    12
1   color   2
2   city    42
3   animal  15
```

I need to get the sum of the colum number e.g.

```
DF1
    A       number
0   name    13
1   color   34
2   city    64
3   animal  27
```

but if I do new = df1 + df2 i get a

```
NEW
    A             number
0   namename        13
1   colorcolor      34
2   citycity        64
3   animalanimal    27
```

I even tried with merge on="A" but nothing. 
Can anyone enlight me pls
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways: one with [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), and one with `concat` and `groupby`. In either case, you need to make sure that your `number` columns are numeric first (your example dataframes have strings):

```
# set `number` to numeric (could be float, I chose int here)
df1['number'] = df1['number'].astype(int)
df2['number'] = df2['number'].astype(int)

# method 1, set the index to `A` in each and add the two frames together:
df1.set_index('A').add(df2.set_index('A')).reset_index()

# method 2, concatenate the two frames, groupby A, and get the sum:
pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby('A',as_index=False).sum()
```

**Output:**

```
        A  number
0  animal      28
1    city      64
2   color      34
3    name      13
```

Comment: thank you!! i will try tomorrow morning!

Comment: thank you sacul, I was trying to use the merge but your solution method 2 (contact) can be used on many DF. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Merging isn't a bad idea, you just need to remember to convert numeric series to numeric, select columns to merge on, then sum on numeric columns via [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df1['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['number'])
df2['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['number'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on='A')
df['number'] = df.select_dtypes(include='number').sum(1)  # 'number' means numeric columns
df = df[['A', 'number']]

print(df)

        A  number
0    name      13
1   color      34
2    city      64
3  animal      28
```

Comment: thanks I tried a merge like yours but didn't test the col number was an int, probably that's why didn't go thought, I will try tomorrow morning, thanks meanwhile!

Comment: Hi jpp, i checked the to merge and dtype of number is already int: A    object
number      int64 dtype: object but if i try to merge on a it gives me 2 columns.. thanks

Comment: @MrDevOn, Yes, of course it gives 2 columns. Because the columns have the same they have to be differentiated (e.g. `number_x`, `number_y`). This is where `df.select_dtypes(include='number').sum(1)` comes into play.

Comment: ohh ok, sorry I missed it, ok now it make sense why I couldn't get it right.. i didn't sum up the 2 columns :( thank you, now is much clear!